# Run angular function on an interval but wait until previous call is completed

Tags: angularjs

I know how to run a function with an interval using angular however what is the cleanest way to run a function every x seconds but wait until the previous call is completed.  Sometimes ajax calls can get stuck and take longer for whatever reason, so I don't want several calls to get clogged up.

Is the best way to just have a boolean flag everytime a call starts and ends and check for that or a more simplified way.

Comment: Show the "non-clean" way that you tried

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$scope.Timer = null

$scope.start = function() {

    $scope.Timer = $interval(function() {
        // do whatever you wanna to do
    }, 1000);

}

$scope.stop = function() {

    if ($scope.Timer) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.Timer);
    }

}
```

stop interval before ajax call and after sucess callback start it again

Answer (score 0):

If ensuring that your method gets called again only after the previous completes its execution is what you want to achieve, you should look at using `$timeout` (or `setTimeout`) instead of `$interval` (or `setInterval`).

```
function runAtAnInterval(){
    // Do stuff
    // Do stuff
    // console.log("do stuff");

    $timeout(runAtAnInterval, 1000);
}
runAtAnInterval();
```

Here's an [excellent article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) explaining how timers work in Javascript.